Refereeing a maths paper with individually poor-quality results which nevertheless combine two very different subfields
I have been asked recently by an editor at a fairly prestigious mathematics journal to referee a longish paper. I feel that there are many factors contributing to an overall difficult situation that I am not sure how to handle. I will try to be as detailed as possible without giving any identifying information.
Effectively, this is a specialist journal which only publishes papers in one area of mathematics. However, this area is sufficiently expansive that it is not unusual whatsoever for two people identifying as researchers in the area to not only have no intersection between their work, but to be so far away from each other that they can't even tell the other what they are doing. The editorial board of this journal is comprised of experts from all over, and they specialize in different things.
In this case, the paper I am asked to referee deals with two very different sub-areas. Arguably the main novelty of this paper is that it exists at all: that these two seemingly vastly disparate sub-areas can find common ground at all. Let us call the two sub-areas A and B respectively.
The main ideas of the paper involving A are actually quite trivial. However, A is a very new sub-area with very few researchers, especially senior ones, who are familiar with it. Thus it is difficult to tell exactly what the landscape is, and how subjects in A compare with those in A', a much older and established sub-area. I have been asked to comment on this issue: specifically, how the main ideas involving A in the paper compare with ideas from A'.
The main ideas of the paper involving B are even more problematic. Indeed, the author appears to be a total novice when it comes to B. Most of the manuscript is proving certain statements involving B, and while I cannot say I have read the arguments in detail, objectively these arguments seem quite unrefined for the following reason: after reading just the statement of their theorem, I was able to come up with an objectively better proof in a couple of hours. Without going into any mathematical details, I can back up my claim as follows: the proof that the author provides is very long, totalling over 40 pages. It is also conditional on a famous conjecture in mathematics. My proof, although I have not written it down, is fairly simple and I cannot imagine it being longer than 5 pages. Further, it involves no unproven hypotheses (so it is an honest-to-goodness proof).
Thus, if the paper is cut into two parts, one consisting of A and the other B, both pieces would be very insipid and hardly worth one's time. Therefore the only reason why it would be considered to be worthy of publication in a highly selective journal is that it manages to weave these two areas together in an interesting way. However, this type of paper already exists in the literature (although there are only a few of them, since like I said sub-area A is very new).
One of the things that give me pause is my own identity as a researcher: I happen to be one of a very small group of mathematicians who are both somewhat familiar with A and also an expert in B. In fact I dare say that there are only a handful of people in the world with a similar pedigree in this context. This makes me worried about my bias, since I no longer find such papers novel simply because it manages to use ideas from both A and B.
Any advice on how I should proceed with the refereeing process?

Is "managing to use ideas from both A and B" the only argument for publication in the current journal? Doesn't sound like a convincing case to me.

Refereeing articles shouldn't be a group project.  The editor trusts you - you need to trust yourself


This makes me worried about my bias, since I no longer find such papers novel simply because it manages to use ideas from both A and B.

I think what you perceive as bias is not bias; rather, it is expertise, which is the opposite of bias. As a proper expert in the subject matter of the paper, you are one of the few people who can give a genuinely well-informed opinion on its strengths (or lack thereof).
In other words, to the extent that your status as an expert makes you predisposed to get less excited about certain things than other less-informed reviewers, it is those other reviewers who would have a “bias”; whereas your own view is closer to being unbiased. And indeed, the journal has sought your opinion as an expert for precisely this reason. What the journal wants to hear is your opinion on the paper, not “your opinion, after applying a corrective function to make your opinion more similar to everyone else’s.”

Any advice on how I should proceed with the refereeing process?

Start by figuring out what you think about the paper. Do you consider it a good paper? Do you think publishing it in a prestigious journal advances the interests of the field? Then write a report making a recommendation in accordance with that view.
If you are unsure, explain what the issue is that is making you unsure, point out the strengths and the weaknesses of the paper as you perceive them, and refrain from making a definite recommendation. The editor will take it from there. (If it is indeed a prestigious journal, in a situation like this the paper will likely be rejected due to the lack of strong support from the reviewer; don’t second-guess such a decision - that is exactly as it should be. Again, stating your honest, unvarnished opinion is the most helpful thing you can do as a reviewer.)

Thank you, this answer helped steel my resolve.

What you have written here sounds like the core of a useful referee report to me (and I am an editor of a journal like the one you describe). Of course, you'd have to add in the details that are (rightfully) absent here. A referee report like this is probably not suitable for the authors, but you can just ask the editor to keep it confidential. (Or even better, split your report into a part that can be shared with the authors, and one just for the editor.)
Ultimately making a decision on what to do is the job of the editor anyway.

Indeed, the perspective you've shared in the text of this question is more or less exactly what the editor wants from you.

+1, though something along these lines sounds like it would be very helpful to the authors indeed. From the description, it sounds like they have the germ of a useful paper (maybe not great, but useful) if they could invest enough expertise in B to polish it. For instance, a sketch of the 5 page proof would likely help them immensely.

Exactly this.  It is the job of the reviewer to highlight the strengths and weaknesses of a paper.  Reviewers ultimately don't decide whether or not a paper should be published.

This sounds like a difficult situation. For situations which are somewhat difficult, one answer is to simply write a report that explains explicitly why the situation is difficult and then let the editors decide what to do with it. Obviously, for reasons of keeping refereeing anonymous, you cannot mention that you are one of the few people who has connected A and B already.  include that in  at the same time that aspect is something as . But everything else is something you can explicitly include.
Edit: Brian below comments that that sort of thing which cannot be seen by the authors should still be included in the remarks that only the editors get to see, and that seems like a good enough point that I'm adding it in here as part of the answer.

"Obviously, for reasons of keeping refereeing anonymous, you cannot mention that you are one of the few people who has connected A and B already." - It should still be shared in the Comments only to the editors field, if one exists.

@Brian Yes, that's a very good point. I'll edit my answer to include that point.

At least in physics there is no requirement for a reviewer to remain anonymous to the author(s). Some reviewers even sign their reports. Based on this answer I guess the convention in math is different, so this is just a comment for people thinking about applying this advice in other fields.

Having a sketch for proof in your head with such a drastic reduction of size might make you a co-author. Can add even more improvements to the paper?
Such a move comes with ethical and technical difficulties, you might be able to navigate them together with the editor and the original authors. For science overall it can be a good thing to have a paper that connects two remote areas of Maths.

Likely unethical for a reviewer to try to jump in to authorship.

Not sure, see for example https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/48086/78796

I am not interested in claiming authorship of this paper.
